# Lie algebras homomorphism induces Lie groups homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a homomorphism between two Lie algebras $\varphi:\mathfrak g\rightarrow \mathfrak h$. Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups with Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ resp. in which cases do we have a corresponding Lie group homomorphism $F:G\rightarrow H$ such that $F$ and $\varphi$ commute with exponential maps?

Comment: $e^Ae^B \ne e^{A+B}$ in general...

Comment: When $G$ is simply connected?

Comment: We need that $G$ and $H$ are connected, and $G$ is simply-connected: see [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/222.pdf), Cor. 4.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, but if $G$ is simply connected yes. This is called Lie's Second Theorem.